# JCombobox hiding the first object's name and editing according to user's input

Tags: java, user-interface, jcombobox

I am making a Java Desktop application. In my application, I am using a JCombobox. Here is an example:

[image: Aplication's main page]

I did not write anything the `JCombobox`.However, first film's name can be seen from the `JComboBox`.

Moreover, Application takes input from the user and according to that input, write something to the `JCombobox`.

```
public class Searchbar extends JComboBox
{
    // PROPERTIES
    AutoCompleteDecorator decorator;
    private final ArrayList<Movie> movies;
    private final DBConnectMovie movieConnection = new DBConnectMovie();
    private final int totalCount = movieConnection.getTotalMovieCount();
    private String item;

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public Searchbar() 
    {
        movies = movieConnection.getAllMovies();

        this.insertItemAt("", 0);
        this.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(movies.toArray()));

        AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(this);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 40)); 

        item = this.getEditor().getItem().toString();
    }

    // METHODS 
    public void changeComboBoxText()
    {
        System.out.println("Prints this out");
        this.getEditor().setItem("C");
    }
}
```

I can print out the text inside the `changeComboBox` method. However, I can not manage to change the `JComboBox`'s text.

Have a beautiful day, thanks!

Comment: `this.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(movies.toArray()));` causes `JComboBox` render whatever you have in `movies`

Comment: But without that how I will show the user the content of the `JComboBox` ?

Answer (score 1):

To change combo: 
a. update `movies`
b.use `this.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(movies.toArray()));`